# Is it possible to show a value label in an Angular Material Multiple Select if the value is empty?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a multi-select and a checkbox triggering select all/none .. it works, but I want it to show "View All" by default (empty value" , only a label, like a custom trigger but it won't work when the value is empty

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by making the empty value matching the default value.

For example:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="gender">
        <mat-option value="">All</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="male">Male</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="female">Female</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

So, making `gender` value equal to `""` (empty string) will make it selected.